# Saving and restoring app settings in C# Forms

Tags: c#

I have a C# Dialog based app. I want to save the preferences/settings the user choose, so that I could reload them in the next run.

I am new to C#, may be this is something quite basic but I do not know. 
Do I have to explicitly write them to a file like ini or something ? or is there a built in way to do that.

The kind of config data is like checkboxes selelected, numericUpDOwn, checkedListbox - checked items etc

Comment: There should be a `Settings.settings` file that comes along with the windows forms project template when you create the project.

Comment: What kind of forms? WPF, SilverLight, WebForms, or WinForms?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the control in the designer.  Scroll all the way up in the Properties window and expand (ApplicationSettings).  Click the indicated button to open a dialog.  Select the property whose value should be persisted (like Checked for a check box) and click New in the dropdown.

[image]

Be a bit careful, not all properties are suitable to be persisted like this.  An example is the form's Size.  You don't want to store the size when the form is minimized or maximized, that size won't restore well.  You need to do this by adding the setting in the Settings designer an only write it when the control is in the right state.  In the case of Size, that's when the Resize event runs and the WindowState is Normal.

Answer (score 4):

After you create the application settings as the other answers suggest, make sure you don't forget to call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`, for example:

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To Create a New Setting at Design Time

**In Solution Explorer, expand the Properties node of your project.**

**In Solution Explorer, double-click the .settings file in which you want to add a new setting. The default name for this file is Settings.settings.**

**In the Settings designer, set the Name, Type, Scope, and Value for your setting. Each row represents a single settings**

For more info you can refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [application settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zszyc6e.aspx). These will persist their values after you close your application, and you will be able to read from them when the program starts back up again.