# Save User Control Properties and Reload

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

I have created a user Control which contains Show property can set to True or False and another property Color which Changes Color of my control. But I want that when user will use in Windows Application then user should be able to change these properties.
How can I do this ???

```
public bool Draw1MinuteTicks
    {
        get { return this.bDraw1MinuteTicks; }
        set { this.bDraw1MinuteTicks = value; }
    }
public Color TicksColor
    {
        get { return this.ticksColor; }
        set { this.ticksColor = value; }
    }
```

I have these Properties.

Comment: please show us what code you have so far

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving and restoring app settings in C# Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359029/saving-and-restoring-app-settings-in-c-sharp-forms)

Answer (score -1):

I think the most easiest way meet Your needs is to use data binding. There are some excellent articles out there, e.g. [Josh Smith's blog post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18270/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-3-Data-binding). Also check out articles dealing with the M-V-VM pattern, e.g. [Barry Lapthorn's blog post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial).

Regards
Jörg