# Loading, updating, and saving time value?

Tags: c#, winforms, time

I'm creating a game you can load and save. I wanted to include details on how long the user has played. I have something like the following to determine the time they spent on the game. How do I save and load their total time? I know I want to put that value into `Properties.Settings` to load and save but I'm at a loss for how I should execute that.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Load previous time
   stopWatch.Start();
}

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && pbPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pnlSave.Bounds))
      {
       string timePlayed;
       stopWatch.Stop();
       TimeSpam timeSpan = stopWatch.Elapsed; //+ Their previous time
       timePlayed = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds);
       MessageBox.Show("You've played for" + timePlayed + ". Game saved!"
       }
       //Save their total time
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving and restoring app settings in C# Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359029/saving-and-restoring-app-settings-in-c-sharp-forms)

Comment: I know I'm using `Properties.Settings` but I need help on how I should approach that.

Comment: What specific problem are you having? You save the data on exit, load it at startup. You need to save the Elapsed, not the string value, so you can load it and add to it during the next run.

Comment: Ok, let me try something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, this solved my answer;

```
    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && pbPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pnlSave.Bounds))
          {
            string timePlayed;
            stopWatch.Stop();
            TimeSpam totalTime = stopWatch.Elapsed + Properties.Settings.savedPlayTime;
            timePlayed = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", Properties.Settings.Default.savedPlayTime.Hours, Properties.Settings.Default.savedPlayTime.Minutes, Properties.Settings.Default.savedPlayTime.Seconds);
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you wish to overwrite your last save of " + timePlayed + "?")== DialogResult.OK)
               {
                 Properties.Settings.Default.savedPlayTime = totalTime;
                 Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                 stopWatch.Reset();
                 MessageBox.Show("Game saved!");
                }
            stopWatch.Start();
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Good job. I could be wrong, but I thought the intention was to show the total time played when they saved.  Shouldn't timePlayed be a string format of totalTime instead?

timePlayed = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", totalTime.Hours, totalTime.Minutes, totalTime.Seconds);

Comment: Terribly sorry, it's a little different on my actual project. I wanted to display the timePlayed on their last save. I could change the MessageBox text I suppose.